# Converting results from a PHP MSSQL query from Latin1_General_CI_AI to a readable string

Tags: php, sql-server, select, encoding, collation

I am querying a CRM2008 database on an MS server from an apache server.

I am trying to get the contactid from a view I have created on the DB.

I return the result fine, but it's not ?encoded? the way I want it.

How can I convert the results from my query into something readable (by me and my code).

```
<?php

ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');

//connect
$dbconn = mssql_connect($Server, $User, $Pass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server");

//select
$selected = mssql_select_db($DB)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");


$query = " select contactid from V_UserDetails where emailaddress1 =
'me@you.com' ";

$result = mssql_query($query);

//grab it
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$user_custid = ($row['contactid']);
}

echo "<b>customer ID:</b> " . $user_custid . "<br />";
```

outputs:

```
customer ID: &<Ǆ���h���"
```

rather than the required:

```
customer ID: 234554345jhg54j34hg54jhg43jh5g34jhg5jhg3jhg34jg
```

Comment: The required customer id makes no sense, it's just ASCII chars. Are you sure that's what's in the database?

Comment: in the database it looks something like this "234554345jhg54j34hg54jhg43jh5g34jhg5jhg3jhg34jg" but when I echo it on my page I get "&<Ǆ���h���"

Comment: Do any of the charsets in this [encoding table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) work for you instead of `UTF-8`?

Comment: I can covert the string and have done to many different charsets, and while it will give me recognized characters, it still doesn't return the content that is actually in the DB? - not sure if its encoding issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is a UniqueIdentifier. In the select query I changed it to

```
$query = " select CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), contactid) from V_UserDetails where emailaddress1 =
'me@you.com' ";
```

And this pulls it from the DB as expected! Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

$data=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9", $data);

ISO-8859-9// change